# Stochastic processes equal in norm are modifications of eachother.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

We can define a normed space of processes by introducing the norm

$\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}\mid X(t)\mid dt<\infty$.

This means that

$\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}\mid X(t)\mid dP dt$, hence if $||X-Y||=0$

we get that

$\int_{\Omega}\mid Y(s)- X(s)\mid dP=0$

Thus $Y=X$ a.s for all $t$, which means that the processes are modifications(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Modification)  of eachother.

Are my implications correct?

Comment: What if $X(t) = 0$ for all $t$ and $Y(t) = 0$ for $t \neq 1$, $Y(t) = 1$ for $t = 1$?

Comment: @Rhys Steele then the last integral is nonzero?

Comment: Yes $\int_\Omega |X(1) - Y(1)| dP = |X(1) - Y(1)| = 1$ but e.g. $\int_0^2 \int_\Omega |X_(t) - Y(t)| dP dt = \int_0^2 1_{1}(t) dt = 0$ and $Y$ is not a modification of $X$. Remember integrating $dt$ only "sees things up to Lebesgue almost surely" so $\|X-Y\| = 0$ only implies that for almost all $t$, $X(t) = Y(t)$ $P$-a.s.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What if $X(t)=0$ for all $t$ and $Y(t)=0$ for $t≠1, Y(t)=1$ for $t=1$?